# Why does reassigning a variable (function parameter) cause "UnboundLocalError:" in Python 3.3?

Tags: python

I find this one entirely confounding. The below code runs fine:

```
def vendor(title, description):
    def validate():
        print("in validate, title: ", title)
        print("in validate, description: ", description)
        convert()
    def convert():
        print("\nin convert, title: ", title)
        print("in convert, description: ", description)
        if title == "fedex":
            pass
            #description = "something else"
    validate()
vendor("ups", "stuff")
```

But substitute `pass` with a reassignment like `description = "something else"` and I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'description' referenced before assignment`. If I take out `print("in convert, description: ", description)` the program runs without error.

What gives? How am I referencing description before assignment? Also, it doesn't seem to matter if a pass `vendor()` "fedex" or something else like "ups" as the title, I still get the error message. How would I go about doing what I'm trying to do - reassign a variable (albeit a function parameter) if a certain condition is True?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are alot of this almost exact answer already on SO ... try looking in the related links on the side of your question

Comment: IIRC if you perform an assignment to a name inside a function it's treated as a function local across the function. You can't assign to the variable you're closing over unless you pass the instance holding it as a member

Comment: Hint - [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal)

Comment: Why on earth is your code structured like that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure what you mean. How could I structure it better?

Comment: Well you could have functions that take arguments rather than relying on scoping, return values or even actually do something.